# How to create transparent border around text on Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, mask

I created the following on Photoshop. I wanted to see if the same can be done on Illustrator (just the typography). I tried clipping masks, but the opposite of what I want is happening i.e. the circle at the center is including the John and Jane text within it, instead of excluding. TIA[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvu7G.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with clipping masks. Pathfinder would also do this, as would compound paths. But presumably you want the text to stay editable.

Do this make the clipping mask out of a square that has a circle on top of it and choose **Object → Compound Mask → Make**. you can then use this as a clipping mask. Thisway you get a inverse clipping mask.

[image]

**Image 1**: Compound path used as clip. Filled with black.

[image]

**Image 2**: Compound path clip applied to text, so that the internals are still editable text.

Other methods:

- Use same mask as a transparency dsource, without making it compound (circle is white)
- Expand and use pathfinder
- Expand and make a compound mask

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the pathfinder for that task. Remember to convert your text objects into vectors before(there's no shortcut for that)